# Hide GRUB2 menu UNLESS you hold down Shift key: how to make this happen?

Tags: multi-boot, grub2

I have a Ubuntu - Windows 7 dual-boot set-up, and I would like to have it that my laptop would boot up Windows 7 unless I press down the Shift key right after boot and bring up the Grub2 menu from which I can choose Ubuntu.

I have tried playing around with combinations with the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` values, but to no avail. I tried setting the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` higher than the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` thinking that both countdown start simultaneously, but no - `GRUB_TIMEOUT` only starts after the other is done.

Is this behavior achievable?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `keystatus` – for example `if keystatus --shift; then` or similar – in `grub.cfg` to set the desired timeout.

Comment: Is there a way to set this in `/etc/default/grub`?